# Is it possible to have a "moving window" in a MYSQL query cache?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, caching

I have a local database with about 1GB of data that I use with a software I made for analysis of financial markets. I call a stored procedure repeatedly from an external application. This stored procedure fetches rows from a `MEMORY` table, performs calculations, and sends the result back to the application.

Each query calls up data from a table which lies within a "window" of a set size (ex. 100,000 `rows`). Every subsequent query shifts the window by 1 row and computes the results.

Is it possible to use the `MySQL` cache in a useful manner with this scenario?

I am currently only the `MEMORY` engine and not `MYISAM` or `InnoDB` for the sake of speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending upon the aggregations you're performing, what might work is to select all the results and handle the windowing client side.

The client can then (replace 1000 with your window size):

1. Read the first 1000 results and calculate the current values.
2. Subtract the first result from the calculation.
3. Read the next result and add to the calculation.
4. Repeat 2 & 3 until all the results are processed.

This way you do not need to enumerate all 1000 results every time you read the next value, changing the algorithm from O(n^2) to O(n).

To get better efficiency when reading, you could use a queue backed by a fixed length circular buffer for storing the current window of results. This will allow you to treat the buffer as a standard queue but without the need to re-shuffle elements in the backing array when adding/removing items.